# List in python for binary converter

Tags: python, list, binary

Im completing a online beginner course in python one of my tasks is to design a simple decimal to binary to hex converter. Ive written the initial code but im a bit stumped on displaying the lists side by side. This is what the course says:

1 Print values 
(for this option display a heading for “denary binary hex” and use your lists to print a table showing the values corresponding to 0 to 15 for each number base i.e.

```
denary      binary      hexadecimal
0           0000            0
1           0001            1
etc
```

This is the code Ive written.

```
binary_list=["0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"]
hex_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","B","C","D","E","F"]
decimal_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
print("What operation would you like to carry out today?")
option=input("Enter choice \n1. See a comparison of the first few decimal numbers converted to binary and hex values\n2. Convert denary number to binary or hex\n3. Convert a hex value between 0 and 15 to denary or binary value\n9. Quit")
print decimal_list
print hex_list 
print binary_list
```

It really dosent work to put them into a table, and im not really sure how to do it. Again I am a first timer with python, and im only meant to be using def statements etc so if you could, please use basic coding.

Thank you all

Comment: This assignment looks [awfully familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752599/list-in-python-for-binary-converter). But yesterday you were a 'tutor'.

Comment: @Martijn: The "awfully familiar" link in your comment is to _this_ question.

Comment: @martineau: I  was just about to correct that: [Python - Binary to Hex to Denary converter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28727916). The similarities go beyond the assignment contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
def toBinary(num):
    return "{0:b}".format(num)

def toHex(num):
    return '{:x}'.format(num)
```

There is no need to store `binary_list` and `hex_list` as we can dynamically compute them.

Comment: This does not seem to address the question of displaying the values side-by-side.